# LAPS - Unable to view passwords but able to decrypt

Tags: windows, active-directory, password-management

I'm testing Windows LAPS on one test OU with one computer in it. Everything is working as expected, except I'm the only user that is able to view the LAPS managed password.

If I run the below, where $cred is one of those other users (testuser1), it works fine. So I don't think it's decryption rights. The other users are in the same LAPS Decryption group as me (configured by GPO).

```
Get-LapsADPassword testcomp -DecryptionCredential $cred

ComputerName        : testcomp
DistinguishedName   : Redacted
Account             : Redacted
Password            : Redacted
PasswordUpdateTime  : 12/26/2023 10:11:45 AM
ExpirationTimestamp : 1/2/2024 10:11:45 AM
Source              : EncryptedPassword
DecryptionStatus    : Success
AuthorizedDecryptor : Redacted
```

If one of the other users logs into Windows and runs the below command, they get nothing back at all. No error, no output, no expiration date, it's basically like you just hit enter on a blank line.

```
PS C:\Users\testuser1> Get-LapsADPassword testcomp
PS C:\Users\testuser1>
```

They're also unable to see it in AD as well. The LAPS tab shows blank admin account name and password, but doesn't show a message about not having decryption rights.

Anyone know what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. I needed to run Set-LapsADReadPasswordPermission on the OU to give my LAPS Decryption group the right to query LAPS passwords.

Example:

```
Set-LapsADReadPasswordPermission -Identity "OU=Test,DC=contoso,DC=com" -AllowedPrincipals "contoso\LAPS_Admins"
```